# Can't get output from cmd

Tags: c#, process, cmd, output, stdout

I'm running this

```
        string path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\c$\Windows\CCM\Logs", computerName);

        Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = string.Format(@"net use {0} && dir {0}", path),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        });

        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + " " + process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But nothing is ever written to the console. What am I doing wrong? I've browsed probably every other SO thread regarding this and done a fair amount of Googling but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `cmd.exe` doesn't close automatically after processing command, it wait for further input, so your program stops at `process.WaitForExit` and not goes to `Console.WriteLine(result)`. Proposed solutions based on event listening or async output should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectStandardOutput = true;` and `RedirectStandardError = true;` will redirect respective streams. To capture those streams, you need to handle `OutputDataReceived` event as follows:

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `/C` option to `cmd.exe` otherwise the child process won't exit.

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

(Type `cmd /?` in your command prompt for more information)

Comment: Point 2. is incorrect. Taken from MSDN `Do not wait for the child process to exit before reading to the end of its redirected error stream. p.WaitForExit(); Read the error stream first and then wait.`

Comment: @Jehof: You're right. I'm sorry. I'll update my post.

Comment: Although your (now deleted) other point was wrong, using the `/c` flag actually helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I´m using the following code to print out the StandardError and StandardOutput of a Process to the Debug/Console

```
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError) {
  string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(result);
}

using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) {
  string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(result);
}

process.WaitForExit();
```

Also i set the following properties on StartInfo

```
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Comment: I have set all those properties on `StartInfo` (except for ErrorDialog) if you take another look at the code above. Thanks for the edit though! :)

Comment: @user1021726 the code is how I set it up in my application, to print out the output from ffmpeg and it works for me. Use the code from the accepted answer when it works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're facing a deadlock as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A deadlock condition results if the parent process calls p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd followed by p.StandardError.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to fill its error stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely for the child process to close its StandardOutput stream. The child process would wait indefinitely for the parent to read from the full StandardError stream.

To avoid this you should use asynchronous read operation on one of the streams:

```
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Courtesy should go to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Probably. I already accepted an answer which also goes into `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` which I think contributed to the solution. I didn't know about the process deadlock though so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but i wanted to share my solution when i came across this thread. No answer suited my needs. I didn't want read output at end of process. So this is the solution i came up with.
The solution solves both fast and slow response and so will always get all the output.

```
...
process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eargs) =>
{
    // do something
};
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eargs) =>
{
    // do something

};

if (timeout > 0)
{
    // if it is a slow process, read async
    if (!process.WaitForExit(200))
    {
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        if (!process.WaitForExit(timeout))
        {
            // show error
            return;
        }

    } else
    {
        // if it is fast process, need to use "ReadToEnd", because async read will not 
        // caputure output
        var text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // do something with text

    }
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer and include some details about how your solution works and how it solves your problem. This helps others to understand your solution. Cheers :)